# How can I use passed data using props in child component v-bind:style?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get data from parent component and use them in child component v-bind:style.

Here's my code.

```html
<body>
        <div id="parentComponent">            
            <child-component v-bind:propsdata="parentBackground" v-bind:propsdata2="parentFontstyle"></child-component>
        </div>

        <script>
            Vue.component('child-component', {
                props: ['propsdata', 'propsdata2'], 
                data: function() {  
                    return {                              
                          childBackground: this.propsdata,
                          childFontStyle: this.propsdata2
                    },               
                template: '<p v-bind:style="childBackgroundColor, childFontStyle">Child componnent Area</p>'
            });

            new Vue ({
                el: '#parentComponent',
                data: function() {  
                     return {                              
                          parentBackground: 'background-color:yellow;',
                          parentFontStyle: 'font-style: italic;'
                    },                      
            })
</body>
```

When I run this code, only second style(childFontStyle) is applied to Child componnent template.

I also tried v-bind:style="[childBackgroundColor, childFontStyle]" and doesn't work.

Is there any way to apply both style?

Comment: Hi, It's a typo, You have defined `parentBackground` in data but as a prop you are passing `parentBackgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the props property as an object and can able to bind the props directly to the child. You have some typo mistakes that need to be fixed as well. Here is the working snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parentComponent">
    <child-component v-bind:propsdata="parentBackground" v-bind:propsdata2="parentFontStyle"></child-component>
  </div>

  <script>
    Vue.component("child-component", {
      template: `<p v-bind:style="[propsdata, propsdata2]">Child componnent Area</p>`,
      props: ["propsdata", "propsdata2"]
    });

    new Vue({
      el: "#parentComponent",
      data: function() {
        return {
          parentBackground: {
            "background-color": "yellow"
          },
          parentFontStyle: {
            "font-style": "italic"
          }
        };
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```